# Get all tf.Variables related to a specific tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a utility function where I give it a tensor `t` and a variable name `n`, and the function returns (it it exists) the `variable` whos name contains `n` and is part of the graph of `t`.

```
def get_variable(t, n):
   #code
   return variable
```

The reason I want to do this is that using Jupyter I often create a graph multiple times while deciding the best structure, but the tensor names keep changing to something like: `{name}_{repetition}:0`, so finding them through `tf.all_variables()` becomes increasingly harder.

It would be easier if I could limit the search to the variables related to a specific tensor because its identifier is of the latest repetition.

Answer (score 2):

*(Warning: I am not going to answer the main question about creating an utility function)*

The reason the tensors have names like: `{name}_{repetition}:0` is not because you add again and again these tensors to the **default graph**.

A solution is to always specify the graph in which you are working with `graph.as_default()`:

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
    var = tf.get_variable('var', [])
    print var.name  # should be 'foo/var:0'
    tensor = tf.constant(2., name='tensor')
    print tensor.name  # should be 'foo/tensor:0'
```

---

If you run it again, you will see the exact same results because the `graph = tf.Graph()` line will create a new graph.

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
    var = tf.get_variable('var', [])
    print var.name  # should be 'foo/var:0'
    tensor = tf.constant(2., name='tensor')
    print tensor.name  # should be 'foo/tensor:0'
```

---

The drawback is that now you cannot rely on the default graph and should pass the graph to compute for example the list of all variables:

```py
print tf.all_variables()  # returns []

with graph.as_default():
  print tf.all_variables()  # returns [...] with all variables
```

Comment: Should I resort to a regex then?

Comment: For me the best way to find a tensor's name is to plot the graph in TensorBoard

Comment: TensorBoard gets messy because of the same problem.

Comment: I think that with my proposed encapsulation, you can choose which graph to load in TensorBoard, so it won't get messy. I am not sure, you would need to verify that.